# Which selenium command can I use to assert an element is not present

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a script in which i will verify if some elements are present and others are not.

> **For the ones which are present I'm using:**

```
verify do
  assert_include(
    @driver.find_element(
      :css,
      "div.launchpadMain > section:nth-of-type(4) > div.launchpadCategoryBody > a:nth-of-type(2)"
    ).text,
    "shiftplan"
  )
 end
```

> **Example for a element which is not present... I'm trying:**

```
verify do
  element_not_present(
    @driver.find_element(:css, "button.btn.btn-icon.pull-right > i")
  )
end
```

---> This is not working though. Which command can I use to make a verification if the element/object is present or not? In this case the element/object is a trash icon.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the group collector `find_elements` (plural), to stop it returning an exception, then assert it's empty.

```
verify do
  assert_empty(
    @driver.find_elements(:css, "button.btn.btn-icon.pull-right > i").size
  )
end
```

find_elements: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium%2FWebDriver%2FFind:find_elements

Comment: Thanks @TomLord, not familiar with that test framework, used to rspec `expect(...).to eq 0` /  `expect(...).to be_empty`. Perhaps there's an `assert_empty` ?

Comment: [Yes, there is](https://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_empty). And actually, that's probably better since it would give a more helpful failure message.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. It's working :). Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Veit-BenediktKramer are you able to accept the answer as correct?

Comment: Yes, i can. Thx guys :)